# Search by list Xamarin Forms (MVVM)

Tags: search, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with searching records. As you type characters, the list will not update.

At the moment I am using Binding Login for testing but I will be using Uri with a photo.

My ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<FollowerModel> _followerItems = null;
public ObservableCollection<FollowerModel> FollowerItems
{
    get => _followerItems;
    set
    {
        _followerItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private FollowerModel _followerItem = null;
public FollowerModel FollowerItem
{
    get => _followerItem;
    set
    {
        _followerItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnFollowerItemChanged();
    }
}

// ...

private  void OnSearchPhrase()
{
    var searchPhrase = _searchPhrase.Trim();

    if (searchPhrase.Length < SEARCH_PHRASE_MIN_LENGTH) return; // SEARCH_PHRASE_MIN_LENGTH = 3

    FollowerItems.Where(name => name.Login.Contains(searchPhrase));
}
```

My PageView

```
<flv:FlowListView SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true" FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding FollowerItemCommand}" FlowColumnMinWidth="100" FlowItemsSource="{Binding FollowerItems}">
    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="98" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="98" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding Login}" /> 
                </Image>-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</flv:FlowListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

First add a search bar in your xaml

```
 <SearchBar Placeholder="Search" Text="{Binding SearchText}"  />
```

Then Create a Bindable property for it

```
private string _searchText;
public string SearchText
{
    get { return _searchText; }
    set
    {
        _searchText = value;
        SearchUserText(_searchText);
        RaisePropertyChanged("SearchText");
    }
}
```

Then Create a function **SearchUserText** that will listen for text and change your list

```
   public void SearchUserText(string text)
    {
          var searchPhrase = _searchPhrase.Trim();

            if (searchPhrase.Length < SEARCH_PHRASE_MIN_LENGTH) return; // SEARCH_PHRASE_MIN_LENGTH = 3

            FollowerItems.Where(name => name.Login.Contains(searchPhrase));

    }
```

NB: Don't forget to add getters and setters on your model **FollowerModel**

example:

```
public class FollowerModel : BindableBase
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this works, it's a better solution than mine, because it's more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need **two ObservableCollections**:

- One `ObservableCollection` which contains all items
- One `ObservableCollection` which contains the filtered items

The filtered `ObservableCollection` will be the one which is binded to your control. So you only need a private variable for all items and a public property for the filtered items:

```
private ObservableCollection<FollowerModel> _allFollowerItems;
private ObservableCollection<FollowerModel> _followerItems;

public ObservableCollection<FollowerModel> FollowerItems
{
    get { return _followerItems}
    set
    {
        _followerItems = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

One more thing I noticed is that you are using `OnPropertyChanged()`. It is deprecated, use **`RaisePropertyChanged()`** instead.

In your `OnSearchPhrase()` method, you want to set `FollowerItems` to the original items (`_allFollowerItems`) if `searchPhrase.Length < SEARCH_PHRASE_MIN_LENGTH`. Otherwise, you will filter it:

```
private void OnSearchPhrase()
{
    var searchPhrase = _searchPhrase.Trim();

    if (searchPhrase.Length < SEARCH_PHRASE_MIN_LENGTH)
    {
        FollowerItems = _allFollowerItems;
    }
    else
    {
        FollowerItems = new ObservableCollection<FollowerModel>(_allFollowerItems.Where(name => name.Login.ToLower().Contains(searchPhrase.ToLower())));
    }
}
```

Notice that I added `ToLower()` to the strings to have a more user friendly search. If Case-sensetive search was intended, just remove it.

Don't forget to set `FollowerItems` and `_allFollowerItems` once when at the place where you are loading your items right now:

FollowerItems = new ObservableCollection(items);
_allFollowerItems = new ObservableCollection(items);